# Display output in comma separated format SQL PLUS spool

Tags: linux, shell

i have a scenario where my table data is below

Table : student : `select * from student;`

```
SNO | SNAME | CITY
1 | ABC | A
2 | PQR | B
```

i want the above table data using sqlplus spool in below format with proper comma separated and no spaces

```
SNO,SNAME,CITY

1,ABC,A

2,PQR,B
```

i have used the below code but not working : giving all above table output in vertical format

```
set feedback off
set heading on
set underline off
set colsep ','
set trimspool on
set pagesize 0

spool student.csv
select * from student;
spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Oracle 12.2.0.1 or higher, you can replace

```
set colsep ','
```

with

```
set markup csv on
```

There are other options like `set markup csv on quote on`, so check the Oracle documentation for details.